# Move element horizontally on scroll, using scrollTop as a negative (jquery)

Tags: jquery, scroll

Here I have my JSFiddle as to where I am at: http://jsfiddle.net/f6hqu47c/

On the fiddle, test2 moves off the screen as you scroll down, perfect! This is the working code for test2:

```
//This code needs to move test2 right on scroll ** Works **
var $horizontal = $('#horizontal-right');
var startPosition = $horizontal.position().left;
var speed = 14;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var newPos = (st * (speed/100)) + startPosition;
    $horizontal.css({
        'left': newPos
    });
});
```

I need to move test so that it too moves off the screen to the left (the opposite way to test2).

I think this will need to use scrollTop as a negative, but I'm not sure how to do this? Any ideas?

## **Edit**

A really simple fix in the end. I just needed a minus in front of it (idiot)! Will leave fiddle up in case else needs something similar.

```
var newPos2 = (st2 * (speed2/100)) + startPosition2;
```

**However**, what I have noticed is (and I cannot replicate this on jsfiddle), the right side element will break on scroll once the page is hard refreshed (cmd+shift click refresh).

It works fine if I just refresh the page normally. What would be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple fix in the end. I just needed a minus in front of it (idiot)! Will leave fiddle up incase else needs something simliar.

```
var newPos2 = (st2 * (speed2/100)) + startPosition2;
```